# WorkManager vs JobScheduler

Tags: android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

In case I can use either **WorkManager** or **JobScheduler**, is there any preference in using JobScheduler? Are there options in JobScheduler that are not available in WorkManager?

Is JobScheduler going to deprecate in future Android versions?

Answer (score 3):

Workmanager internally uses AlarmManger, Jobscheduler or Firebase Job Dispatcher based on Android API level so I don't think Jobscheduler will get deprecated.

Workmanger handles all scenario for you and also has easy to use API but beware that right now its in alpha stage so you may end up with some issues.